# What frequency accuracy specification for cellular phone hand set? How is it achieved?

Tags: frequency, cellphone, accuracy

What are '**the industry standard' frequency accuracy specification**, in ppm or ppb, for cellular phone hand set?

**How is it achieved**? is TCXO (temperature compensated) enough?  Does OCXO (oven control) needed?

Does handset frequency control **works along** or it works with base stations to 'exchange calibration data' to enhance accuracy?

How can the needed accuracy achieved in very very low cost phone? (phone only, small screen, no camera, no add on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no "Industry Standard". Each Protocol specifies an allowable frequency error. For example, according to this R&S document https://www.rohde-schwarz.co.jp/events/webinar/lte_ue_rf_measurements_v122.pdf

LTE requires 0.1PPM transmit accuracy, referenced to the received frequency. It's achieved by using a TCXO in a control loop, with the received frequency used as a reference, so it does work with the base station to control the frequency.

The Feature phone at $20 or $30 actually costs more than that, handsets in the US are subsidized by the carriers, so what you pay is a fraction of what the carrier paid.

Comment: Any details on how the received signal can be used as reference for transmit?  Hardly imagine that on traditional superhetrodyne style analogue receiver. May be it use different working principle?

Comment: There are many feature phones that have a **retail** of <$30, without any subsidy. Take a look [here](http://www.dx.com/c/cell-phone-599/cell-phones-511/feature-phones-531).